# Side effect in MUI Modal

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog, use-effect

I use React 17.0.1 and Material-UI 4.11.2 in my project.
When I try to make a side effect for modal in the useEffect hook it executes before a modal rendering.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Modal } from '@material-ui/core';

const MyModal = ({ sideFunction, isModalVisible, closeModal }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        sideFunction();
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <Modal open={isModalVisible} onClose={closeModal}>
            <div>MODAL</div>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to render your model conditionaly where you have used this model.
instead of:

```
<MyModal ...props />
```

Use Like this:

```
{isModalVisible && <MyModal ...props />}
```

Comment: I did not write but I've used MyModal this way. It doesn't affect on execution of useEffect before rendering.